Is there a Salem-Spencer set whose sum of reciprocals is greater than that of Szekeres's sequence?
Edit: My question is basically the same as This question, which I think remains unanswered, although  in the comments,
ReverseFlowControl claims to have found a sequence, but I don't understand their construction (in fact, I think they didn't realise that the sequences have to be increasing sequences of natural numbers).

In the comments to this question, Henry suggests that the sum of reciprocal of Szerekes's sequence is $\approx 3.0079\ldots,$ and I'll assume this is fairly accurate for the sake of argument.

My question is: Is it known if there is a Salem-Spencer Set - that is,
a set of $3-$term A.P.-free natural numbers - whose sum of reciprocals
is greater than $3.0079\ldots?$ Or is $3.0079\ldots$ the supremum of all such sets? I am interested in a proof that there exists such a supremum (which I suspect there is, although I'm not certain of this), whatever the supremum is.

I think I have seen somewhere*, that there are asymptotically denser Salem-Spencer sets than Szekeres's sequence** - however, this wouldn't answer my question above.
Possibly relevant is this paper.

Let $A$ be the set of numbers in Szekeres's sequence. And for example, $4A+3$ means the set, $\{4a_n+3: a_n\in A\}.$ My main attempt to construct sets satisfying the desired property, has been $(3A-2)\cup (3A-1).$ This appears to be identical to Szekeres's sequence, probably due to the alternative "ternary-binary" definition of Szekeres's sequence. Next, I looked at $(7A-6)\cup (7A-5)\cup (7A-3),$ and a few more of this type, but then Szekeres's sequence seems to dominate/(weakly?) majorize these sequences, so the sum of their reciprocals will be $<3.0079\ldots.$

*although I can't remember where - I think it was a paper released recently i.e. last year or this year). If someone knows the paper I am talking about then please post it in the comments
**although this result may have been found by Erdos et al.

Perhaps I should delete this question as it is basically a duplicate of the linked question? And maybe add my two cents in the comments to that question?

I think you're right that the answer to the linked question doesn't actually address the sum of reciprocals. Specifically, while Behrend's construction is more dense asymptotically, the construction selects from integers which have digits $0,\dots,b-1$ in base $2b$. These already have a finite sum of reciprocals: there are $b^k-b^{k-1}$ such integers with $k$ digits, all of which are at least $(2b)^{k-1}$, which gives us a sum of $2b-2$. Then, Behrend's construction picks out roughly a $1/(k b^2)$ fraction of the ones with at most $k$-digits. This fails to improve on the greedy construction.

**Did you mean this paper? https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X98003859

No, but that could be relevant.
